# FirebaseUser is null при передаче в метод

Tags: android, firebase

Создаю верификацию для приложения, поэтому использую два объекта

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
```

Написал отдельный метод, который получает на вход объект `FirebaseUser`

```
private void emailVerification(FirebaseUser user){
    user.sendEmailVerification()
        .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                notificationToast("Verify email address");
            } else {
                notificationToast("Verification error");
            }
        });
}
```

Но возникает проблема, в метод попадет  `null` объект, хотя через `debugger` объекты `FirebaseAuth` и `FirebaseUser` не `null`

Полный код методов

```
private void buttonClickSignUp(){
    String mail = inputMail.getText().toString();
    String pass = inputPassword.getText().toString();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mail) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)){

        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); //auth not null

        createAccount(mail, pass, auth);

        FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser(); //user not null

        emailVerification(user); //user is null
    } else {
        notificationToast(MAIL_PASS);
    }
}

private void createAccount(String email, String password, FirebaseAuth auth){
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                router.replaceScreen(KeyFragments.AUTHENTICATION_FRAGMENT);
            } else {
                notificationToast("Registration Error");
            }
        });
}

private void emailVerification(FirebaseUser user){
    user.sendEmailVerification()
        .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                notificationToast("Verify email address");
            } else {
                notificationToast("Verification error");
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Может это из за createAccount, что он в другом потоке что то делает с авторизацией? Я думаю нужно createAccount вызывать если user==null. Может сперва FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser(), а потом - if(user==null){createAccount}

Comment: Как то обошлось, ничего особенного не менял, но заработало